# PHP date showing wrong time despite the timestamp being correct

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm having a problem with the PHP date function which I've never had a problem with before.

The timestamp is entirely correct, however for some bizarre reason date() is outputting a time which does not correspond.

I have the following timestamp (and this is definitely the correct one - when I echo it out onto the page, as well as in the database, it shows as being correct):

```
464400
```

Yet when I use the following line of code:

```
<?php echo date("H:i",$timestamp); ?>
```

I'm getting a time of 4 am? If I paste the timestamp into a timestamp converter website, then it shows the time should in fact be 9am.

I'm completely stuck, this has never happened to me before & this problem has only just come up recently - the code hasn't been changed and everything seemed to be working correctly before.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That time stamp is is 9am GMT timezone, if you are in another timezone then you will need to adjust it accordingly.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

or even better in your php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

```
date.timezone="Europe/London"
```

Or you can use more specifically GMT instead of Europe/London (which has DST)

Answer (score 5):

try this method will work

for time zone
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 

$dt2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $dt2;

?>
```

Comment: `$dt2` is unecessary. just 
`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
//define unix timestamp
$timestamp = 1456778973;
// output
echo date('d M Y H:i:s',$timestamp);
```

Try this converter too http://freeonlinetools24.com/

Answer (score 0):

For time zone: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`

`echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s A");`