# Small issue PHP date / strtotime function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm having a small problem in my code. I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 times.

This is my code:

```
$dif = strtotime($tt['endtime']) - strtotime($tt['starttime']);
echo date("H:i", $dif);
```

$tt['endtime'] = 13:00 and $tt['starttime'] is 12:00 so the output is supposed to be 01:00, but the output is 02:00.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `date` expects a unix timestamp, not the difference between 2.

Comment: You are trying to convert date difference to date. What will happen when you have May 4 11:00 and May 5 11:00?

Comment: how would you like to show the format as what you are doing currently is passing the difference which is wrong, you need to convert those manually

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – you are using pure times as if they were dates. The result of your difference is `3600` - so that is 3,600 seconds from when the unix epoch started, so 1.1.1970 0:00:00. And since you are formatting that as a date again, the time zone comes into play. If the time zone has summer/winter time, then you most likely have winter time on 1.1.1970. So one hour difference.

Comment: If you insist echoing in that format, you can add your `$dif` to `00:00`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date showing wrong time despite the timestamp being correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526129/php-date-showing-wrong-time-despite-the-timestamp-being-correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the output from `date()` is "altered" by the timezone your server is in. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526129/php-date-showing-wrong-time-despite-the-timestamp-being-correct) for more information.

Instead you can use [`gmdate()`](https://php.net/gmdate) for that (no issues with timezones):

```
$endtime = "13:00";
$starttime = "12:00";
$difference = abs(strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime));
echo gmdate("H:i", $difference);
// 01:00
```

See https://3v4l.org/BkRFM for output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for time subtraction

```
$tt['endtime']   = '13:00:00';
$tt['starttime'] = '12:00:00';

$dif = strtotime($tt['endtime']) - strtotime($tt['starttime']); //here you can subtraction occurs

echo gmdate("H:i", $dif);  // In this step you got the correct output 01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gmdate()

```
$dif = strtotime('13:00')-strtotime('12:00');
echo gmdate("H:i", $dif);
```