# How to fix PHP timezone issue with date function

Tags: php, timezone

```
echo (date('d-m-Y',strtotime("1997-02-27T00:00:00+08:00")));
```

The result of this is one day before. 26-02-1997

I have an API that brings time like the format above. How can I implement timezone to date function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526129/php-date-showing-wrong-time-despite-the-timestamp-being-correct

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default timezone with [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). The list of timezones for that is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
echo (date('d-m-Y',strtotime("1997-02-27T00:00:00+08:00")));
```

My current timezone is 26-02-1997, this makes it Australian: 27-02-1997.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked for me. And is there any way to get this timezone from client's location or browser dynamically?

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone).. you can find the rough idea of a timezone (well.. language) in the HTTP header's accepted language (en-US etc), so that's where I'd look if I didn't want to deal with too much JavaScript.

Comment: You can change it dynamically to your liking (or even use several time zones at the same time with `DateTime` objects) but you need to be aware that PHP is a server-side language. It doesn't need or interact with browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open the php.ini file and set this code `date.timezone = "US/Central"` to define definitely.

You can check if alright on section date using the command:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```